# Please explain DEFER's behaivour in golang

Tags: go, deferred-execution

As I know, defer is usually used to close or free resources.
And using `defer FUNC ()` inside the block (function) of the code ensures that `FUNC ()` will call in case of any return from this block(function) or panic in this block (function).

So - how to explain `defer` behavior in this code: ([Example](https://play.golang.org/p/FPA0wrRyw1f)):

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "errors"
)
func test() error {
  err := errors.New("some error")
  return err
}
func main() {
  if err := test(); err!=nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR EXIT")
    return
  }
  defer fmt.Println("DEFER EXIT")
  fmt.Println("NORMAL EXIT")
}
```

I expected to see this:

```
ERROR EXIT
DEFER EXIT
```

But got it:

```
ERROR EXIT
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: the defer never runs, so the fmt.Println isn't set up.  When the return occurs in the line above there is no defer waiting to happen

Comment: Code within a function is executed in the order expressed by that code. You can't expect a `defer` to happen if it was never executed.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12

Answer (score 4):

You return from the main function before the `defer` statement could be executed, before the `fmt.Println()` call could be "enqueued".

Change it to:

```
defer fmt.Println("DEFER EXIT")
if err := test(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR EXIT")
    return
}
fmt.Println("NORMAL EXIT")
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8ijKc8npJXF)):

```
ERROR EXIT
DEFER EXIT
```

Comment: How about this:

`func _httpHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
 if err != nil {
  http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
  log.Println(remoteIP, "\t",err.Error())
  return   
 }
   defer r.Body.Close()
}
`

Comment: @Борис How about that what?

Comment: sorry - wrong example.

Comment: found all answers here - http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/#anameclose_http_resp_bodyaclosinghttpresponsebody